# Transparent Shader can't apply metallic and smoothness

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have this shader that needs to render a see-through hole of a human body and I have used a transparent shader to see though the model. I have solved the z-depth buffer issue of the model but I can't seems to apply metallic and smoothness on the shader. Any advice? Thank you very much.
[image]
The following are the shader:

```
![Shader "Custom/test2" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
        SubShader{
        Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }

        // extra pass that renders to depth buffer only
        Pass{
        ZWrite On
        ColorMask 0

    }

        // paste in forward rendering passes from Transparent/Diffuse
        UsePass "Transparent/Diffuse/FORWARD"
    }
        Fallback "Transparent/VertexLit"
}][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, you are using a pass which is [Diffuse light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffuse_reflection) only... If you want metallic and smoothness, why don't you just use a surface shader and paste in your primer pass there?

Create a new surface shader. To make it support transparency, you need to add the following things,

Your tags must look like this:

```
Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent"}
```

Add this to the start of the subshader:

```
ZWrite Off
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

And the surface pragma must include alpha:fade, like this:

```
#pragma surface surf Standard alpha:fade
```

Add your primer pass inside the SubShader but before the CGPROGRAM block. Inside the surf function, set the different values like you would in a normal surface function. You can read more about surface shaders here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html